# Using pandas within web applications - good or bad?

Tags: python, pandas, flask

Is it okay to use python pandas to manipulate tabular data within a flask/django web application?

My web app receives blocks of data which we visualise in chart form on the web. We then provide the user some data manipulation operations like, sorting the the data, deleting a given column. We have our own custom code to perform these data operations which it would be much easier to do it using pandas however I'm not sure if that is a good idea or not?

Answer (score 2):

It’s a good question, pandas could be use in development environment if dataset isn’t too big , if dataset is really big I think you could use spark dataframes or rdd, if data increase in function of time you can think on streaming data with pyspark.

Answer (score 2):

Actually yes, but don't forget to move your computation into a separate process if it takes too long.